# Is there a concise term or abbreviation for "Decimal Places"?

Tags: abbreviations, concision

> Is there a concise term or abbreviation for "Decimal Places"?

I have a table that I'm trying to squeeze in information and the column header is wider than the information it contains.

*Context:*

```
Value        Decimal Places <---too long!
_____________________________________
10.12               2
1.123               3
```

I've considered *precision*, but it has another meaning in the context of the table.  At this stage, the best I've come up with is *decimals*.

Note: I need to explicitly state the number of decimals.

Comment: `decimals` seems clear to me. remember it's just a label in a table - your grade school english teacher is not watching.

Comment: @sgroves - What about your grade school math teacher?

Comment: i'm not sure why a math teacher would care what you label a table :)

Comment: I refer you to ScotM's answer below. Besides using a key to clarify the meaning, you might be able to use mouseover text to expand/explain the abbreviation.

Comment: In my experience (without a reference, I admit) just `places` is commonly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I appreciate the input from everyone.  While I like the idea of an abbreviation, I've never seen DP used for decimal places (although you have my up vote for the concept and source).  I've explained in the question that precision is out and I'm not convinced that decimals conveys the same meaning as decimal places, so I'm considering the following:

```
Value            Decimal 
                 Places
_____________________________________
10.12               2
1.123               3
```

*I'll anticipate some down votes as this is not an EL&U usage answer so much as a simple change to formatting.*

Answer (score 4):

[***DP***](http://www.abbreviations.com/abbreviation/Decimal+Places) is the official abbreviation for "decimal places".

http://www.abbreviations.com/abbreviation/Decimal+Places

If there is concern about ambiguity, it is always appropriate to provide a ***[key](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/key)*** describing the labels for clarity.

> Noun
>
> An explanatory list of symbols used in a map, table, etc.

Comment: It may be the "official" definition, but I've never, ever seen it used.  "Precision" is probably the first choice for a term.  (Can't think of a good second choice right now.)

Comment: @HotLicks: +1 for your first sentence, and +1 for "precision".

Comment: the asker should use the smallest word that best conveys their intended meaning to their audience. if everyone who reads this table would instantly understand what *DP* means, this is a great answer. i doubt that is the case, though. context is everything.